# Getting Unusual Error while using Selenium and PhantomJS in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm trying to fill the forms of [these page](http://www.anbima.com.br/reune/reune.asp), I checked the HTML code and the forms that I'm looking for are there but when I run my code, I got an error that I never seen in selenium.

I'm using PhantomJS 2.1.1 in Python 3.6.1 with Selenium.

I Want to fill these form.

```
<input type="text" name="Dt_Ref" value="31/08/2017" maxlength="10" size="10" class="form_data" onBlur="formatCamp(this, 'date');javascript:if(REUNE.Dt_Ref.value!=REUNE.Dt_RefAnt.value){REUNE.target='_self';REUNE.action='reune.asp';REUNE.submit()};" onKeyPress="return(validaConteudo(event, this, 'date'))" onKeyUp="saltaCampo(event, this, 'date',8)" onFocus="removeCaracs(this, 'date')">  <a style="cursor:hand; cursor:pointer;" onclick="openCalendar(document.REUNE.elements['Dt_Ref']);return false;">
```

My Code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver


url = 'http://www.anbima.com.br/reune/reune.asp'
path_phantom = 'C:\\Users\\TBMEPYG\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe'

#Processing

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path= path_phantom)
driver.get(url)
name = driver.find_element_by_name("Dt_Ref")
driver.quit()
```

And I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\Desktop\beta_anbima.py", line 11, in <module>
    name = driver.find_element_by_name("Dt_Ref")
  File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 426, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 832, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 297, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\TBMEPYG\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: {"request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"89","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:64945","User-Agent":"Python http auth"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"name\", \"value\": \"Dt_Ref\", \"sessionId\": \"cc170460-8e5e-11e7-ad22-8d3d940cf70e\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/cc170460-8e5e-11e7-ad22-8d3d940cf70e/element"}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

This is the first step of my code. I'm under a bank proxy and this could be the problem. When I access from my Chrome, the page works fine.
When I try to use the same code (changing the url and the element name) in [this site](http://pythonscraping.com/pages/files/form.html), it works fine.

Thank you all.

Comment: Works fine with `Chrome` on windows.

Comment: Any ideia about why this doesnt work on phantomJS? My network is restricted and I cant download the Chrome's web driver

Comment: No idea, try with `Firefox` if you have the driver.

Comment: I don't have too. It has to be with phantomJS ):

Comment: Try to select the element by `xpath`. See if it works.

Comment: I Will try. You know what is the xpath for this form?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153397/discussion-between-md-khairul-basar-and-thales-marques).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue/bug with PhantomJS.

I would suggest you use Chrome as such or docker image for `selenium/standalone-chrome`

If you look at https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues there are `1923` open issues, which speaks for itself.

You can't even query

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*")
```

You will get the error

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: {"request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"87","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:53425","User-Agent":"Python http auth"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"xpath\", \"value\": \"//*\", \"sessionId\": \"eb09e680-8e72-11e7-8b72-d1137b47fa59\"}","url":"/elements","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"elements","directory":"/","path":"/elements","relative":"/elements","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/elements","queryKey":{},"chunks":["elements"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/eb09e680-8e72-11e7-8b72-d1137b47fa59/elements"}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

So open a bug and make the count `1924`, but I really doubt you would get much help

Comment: Understood. Is there any possibility of using chrome as a headless browser?

Comment: Yes you can use that by creating `ChromeOptions`. Also use headless only if it works, i have seen other issues with headless where it is not same as chrome, some websites not working fine. So check if yours work and if it works then use it.

Comment: @ThalesMarques Read this https://intoli.com/blog/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome/ .  From what I have heard with new headless, you can't use extensions.  An easier way is just to use chrome options though if you have linux it is better to run it the headless through the most recent Chrome rather than chrome options